# What is the right way to expose a private Java9 module's package to JUnit?

Tags: java, gradle, java-9

I have an "executable" Java 9 module (meaning it won't expose any packages, it just contains a `main` function) which I need to test.

I am using Gradle's `java-library` and `org.gradle.java.experimental-jigsaw` plugins.

I have some package-private methods I need to test, and when I run in IntelliJ the tests work, but when running with Gradle, I get many errors like this:

```
abc.MyClassTest > myTestMethod FAILED
java.lang.IllegalAccessException
```

In the Gradle report, I see the root of the error:

```
class org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner (in module junit) 
cannot access class abc.MyClassTest (in module com.my.mod) 
because module com.my.mod does not export abc to module junit
```

If I add this to my `module-info.java` file, it works with a warning:

```
exports abc to junit; // I don't really want to export this
```

Warning (when compiling):

```
warning: [module] module not found: junit
```

This looks pretty horrible even without the warning, in my opinion.

My question: how to "open" this package for tests only to avoid warnings and errors?

Comment: Yep, I agree it looks frightening. Please, notice: org.gradle.java.`experimental`, so it is probably a bug.

Comment: You shouldn't need anything in your module-info.java for this. Instead, you will use command line arguments to patch and augment the module. definition. The Maven Compiler and Surefire plugins do this for you, Gradle may be a bit behind on this. For starters, you say you are testing package private methods so this means the tests are in the same package you are testing. Does this mean you have figured out --patch-module? Next is exporting the packages to JUnit with --add-exports but you need to get JUnit's module name first.

Comment: I can't find documentation for these options. Where are they defined?

Comment: `java -help`, the JDK docs, and JEP 261 has all the details about these options.

Comment: haha... `java -help` does not even mention these options :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the Gradle Plugin is still experimental (6 months after the release of Java 9), it seems it still has some bugs and missing features.

But here's how to work around the issue while the Gradle devs don't improve the situation.

Add this to your build file:

```
test {
    doFirst {
        jvmArgs += [
                '--add-exports', "module/package=junit",
        ]
    }
}
```

Where `module/package` is the name of the module and package you need to make visible to JUnit.

This is basically equivalent to the `exports package to junit` clause in `module-info.java`, but without having the clause make into the compiled jar!

This option is not documented in `javac -help`, but you can at least find it mentioned in the [Oracle JDK Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#JSWOR627) and, more thoroughly, in [JEP-261](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261)... see the `Breaking encapsulation` section.