# How to get Gradle to run Kotlin tests under Java 10?

Tags: java, gradle, junit, kotlin

Gradle says it supports Java 10 now, but it seems that's only if you don't have tests to run.

Even Java tests [may have trouble running](https://github.com/zyxist/chainsaw/issues/36), but there [are workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285412/what-is-the-right-way-to-expose-a-private-java9-modules-package-to-junit).

However, I have been really struggling trying to run Kotlin tests in a Java-only (as in, only Java code runs in production, but only Kotlin tests) project.

I was using the `chainsaw` plugin but it's full of bugs and [doesn't do things correctly](https://github.com/zyxist/chainsaw/issues/35), so I am trying with just the normal `java` and Kotlin plugins.

I followed the [Gradle guide](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/) to build Java 9/10 modules and noticed that,as the Chainsaw plugin, they incorrectly advise to use this code to "patch" the Java module:

```
'--patch-module', "$moduleName=" + files(sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs).asPath
```

This will only include Java classes, so it doesn't work for Groovy or Kotlin or any other JVM language.

I fixed it by using this instead:

```
'--patch-module', "$moduleName=" + test.getTestClassesDirs().asFileTree.asPath
```

Now, every class file is listed in `patch-module` but my tests still won't run.

Does anyone know what I may be missing in order to get the tests running again (they worked fine with Java 8)?

Comment: I think it should rather be `configurations.testRuntimeClasspath` than `test.getTestClassesDir()` – the former includes all the classes that should be present on the classpath when the tests are run, while the latter only points Gradle to the directory where it should locate classes containing tests to run.

Comment: No, that causes all sorts of weird errors like this (because it adds all modules in classpath to my module): `Module mymodule contains package org.eclipse.jetty.http.pathmap, module jetty.http exports package org.eclipse.jetty.http.pathmap to mymodule`